# Can a jQuery Droppable interact with a non-Draggable element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, touch, draggable

Or, another way to perhaps word it: can a non-Draggable element be 'disguised' as a Draggable in the eyes of a droppable?

The situation is that I'm trying to implement a workaround for the fact that jQuery Draggables and Droppables are not touch enabled. There are workarounds to this (such as Touch-Punch) but they still are emulating the touch by translating to the mouse events that a jQuery Draggable is listening for.

This is a problem for me as the particular goal I'm after is to allow a user to drag two elements with two separate drag interactions simultaneously--which one obviously can't do with a mouse--so just isn't supported by jQuery UI.

I found this as an alternative to the Draggable: https://github.com/heyman/jquery-draggable-touch

It's not nearly as robust as a default jQuery draggable, as there aren't handy parameters such as 'revert'. But not a huge deal. I can rewrite those features as needed.

However, I'd rather not rewrite all the logic that I've already built around the built-in functionality of a droppable. For example: getting the dropped item from within the droppable configuration via `ui.droppable`--or just trying to figure out if it there was even an element dropped upon it.

Is there a way for an element to be 'seen' as a jQuery draggable by a jQuery droppable without actually being a jQuery draggable?

UPDATE:

I've discovered I can use this draggable-touch AND jQuery's draggable at the same time...draggable for mouse, draggable-touch for touch. Nice.

However, I still have to integrate the touch event into the fold and to do that, ideally, I could manually calculate the position of the dragged item and if it is above a droppable element, I could `.trigger` the drop event. Alas, I can't find the correct syntax for triggering a drop event on a droppable.